# How to get list of objects in MySQL 8 based on coordinates spatial

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, mysql-8.0

I have a MySQL 8 db that stores for example

```
id        int,    -> 1
name      String, -> Hosp One
address   String, -> 8900 North Kendall Drive
lat       double, -> 25.6870576
lng       double  -> -80.33634669999999
```

and after i get the coordinates of zipcode, via google maps api.

**i.e 33175 -> lat: 25.735712, lng: -80.399265**

with MySQL I know i can now query and retrieve with spatial data types and have the SRID set to 4326 but don't know if i should create a new table from start or my current table is suffice.

Also i don't exactly know how to do the query search and return a list of hospitals **List < Hospital >** within a **radius/ distance** of **X miles** of said zipcode/ coordinates

**Service**

```java
// package info here
import com.google.maps.errors.ApiException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import static com.Utils.Utils.*;

@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class HospitalService {
    private final HospitalRepository hospitalRepository;

    @Autowired
    public HospitalService(HospitalRepository hospitalRepository) {
        this.hospitalRepository = hospitalRepository;
    }

    public Optional<Hospital> findById(String id) {
        int parsedInt = Integer.parseInt(id);
        return hospitalRepository.findById(parsedInt);
    }

    public Iterable<Hospital> findAllHospital() {
        return hospitalRepository.findAll();
    }


    public Iterable<Hospital> createHospital(List<Hospital> hospitals) throws InterruptedException, ApiException, IOException {
        List<Hospital> newHosp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Hospital hosp : hospitals) {
            newHosp.add(createLatCord(hosp));
        }
        return hospitalRepository.saveAll(newHosp);
    }

    public List<Hospital> findHospitalByZipcode(String zipcode) throws InterruptedException, ApiException, IOException {

       // ZipodePoint is a custom method that returns the cordinates of zipcode in a Point obj
      // i.e x=25.735712, y=-80.399265
        System.out.println(ZipodePoint(zipcode));
        return null;
    }

}
```

**My Controller**

```java
@GetMapping(path = "search/{zip}", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public List<Hospital> findHospitalByZipcode(@PathVariable String zip) throws InterruptedException, ApiException, IOException {
    return hospitalService.findHospitalByZipcode(zip);
}
```

**Repo**

```java
// package name here

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface HospitalRepository extends CrudRepository<Hospital, Integer> {

}
```

**Hospital Model**

```java
// Package name

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Hospital {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String zipcode;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private double lat;
    private double lng;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="hospital")

    public Hospital() {
    }

    // All the other field Getters and Setters

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(double lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }
}
```

Comment: In HospitalRepository, write a method like: Hospital findByLatLng(Double lat, Double lng) and call it from service. LatLng should be the name of your entity's field.

Answer (score 0):

In HospitalRepository, write a method like:

```
Hospital findByLatLng(Double lat, Double lng);
```

and call it from service. LatLng should be the name of your entity's field. 
Or write a query like following -

```
@Query("SELECT h FROM Hospital h where h.lat = ?1 And h.lng = ?2")
Hospital findByLatLng(Double lat, Double lng);
```

For taking list of objects, write method as follows:

```
@Query("SELECT h FROM Hospital h where h.lat = ?1 And h.lng = ?2")
List<Hospital> findByLatLng(Double lat, Double lng);
```

Comment: tried to run it in MySQL Workbench but kept getting > Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?1 And lng = ?2' at line 1 ... also don't know it would return the hospitals within X miles of radius.

Comment: It's not for mysql workbench, it should write in your java code

Comment: ah ok but when i run it, i get no Hospitals nearby,  it only responds with object that match lat and lng i passed in the url like url/lat_lng. So if the url/lat_lng matches any hosp in my db i get ALL of them and if it doesn't match i get no results. I'm trying to find any hosp within x miles radius

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such feature in mysql. I think, you have to calculate range of lat lng like minLat, maxLat .. and compare that range data to repository method.

Comment: i managed to find a basic formula to find the results, but i can run it in MySQL Workbench but can't seem to translate it into Java Query code -> 
    @Query("SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(25.735712) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians( -80.399265) ) + sin( radians(25.735712) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM hospital HAVING distance < 8.5 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20")

Comment: Great!! You can use native query in Java code, like -@Query(value="SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(25.735712) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians( -80.399265) ) + sin( radians(25.735712) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM hospital HAVING distance < 8.5 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20", nativeQuery = true)